# Initialize class attribute with a method

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes, initialization

(Final) EDIT : Ok, so I'm a total dumbass. My identation was made so that all my methods after the `__init__` were actually inside my `__init__`. It's a syntax mistake.

I'd like to know if I can initialize a variable with a method (member of the class). Basically, it looks like this :

```
class Tile:
    def __init__(self, x, y, tile_type):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._tile_type = tile_type
        self._color = my_method()

(further in class)
    def my_method(self):
        #my definition
```

Currently, it gives me an error :

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'my_method' referenced before assignment
```

The problem is that I declare a 2d array with a comprehension list like this

```
[[Tile(i,j,0) for i in range(Y_SIZE)] for j in range(X_SIZE)]
```

So I'd like to avoid a second nested loop to put the return value of `my_method()` in the class attribute `_color`, if it's possible.

Thanks !

EDIT : as asked, I will be more specific : I want to assign the value returned by `my_method()` to `_color`. And sorry about the indentation, `my_method(self)` is actually in the `Tile` class.

For those who actually want the full code of the class :

```
class Tile:
    def __init__(self, x, y, tile_type):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._tile_type = tile_type
        self._color = self.set_color_variation()

        def _get_x(self):
            return self._x

        def _set_x(self, x):
            self._x = x

        x = property(_get_x, _set_x)

        def _get_y(self):
            return self._y

        def _set_y(self, y):
            self._y = y

        y = property(_get_y, _set_y)

        def _get_color(self):
            return self._color

        def _set_color(self, color):
            self._color = color

        color = property(_get_color, _set_color)

        def _get_tile_type(self):
            return self._tile_type

        def _set_tile_type(self,tile_type):
            self._tile_type = tile_type

        tile_type = property(_get_tile_type, _set_tile_type)

        def set_color_variation(self):
            _color = make_color(TILE_COLOR[_tile_type], TILE_COLOR_VARIATION[_tile_type])
```

And the error message it currently gives me :

```
AttributeError: 'Tile' object has no attribute 'set_color_variation'
```

If I write

```
self._color = set_color_variation()
```

It gives me :

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'set_color_variation' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: As currently written, `my_method` isn't actually in `Tile`, although you don't access it via `self` anyway; please give a [mcve] with the full error traceback to clarify the issue.

Comment: Do you want `self._color` to be the result of calling `my_method()`, or do you want it to contain a reference to the method itself?

Comment: You can pass my_method as an argument in you constructor like this        `def __init__(self, x, y, tile_type, my method)`

Comment: As I said in the edit I just made, I want `self._color` to contain the return value of `my_method()`. Sorry for the ambiguous statement.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, just do: `self._color = self.my_method` in your constructor.

Comment: Maybe, but I suspect the OP actually wants the value returned by the method, i.e., `self._color = self.my_method()`.

Comment: Right, I may have misinterpreted the question. That makes more sense in this case :)

Comment: It's always tricky answering ambiguous questions. But I'm pretty sure the OP wants `._color` to be set to the value returned, due to the phrase "apply my method on the class attribute".

Comment: Yes, sorry for the ambiguous statement. That's exactly what I want, set `_color` to the return value of `my_method()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
class Tile:
    def __init__(self, x, y, tile_type, method):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._tile_type = tile_type
        self._color = method()

def my_method():
    # Write you logic here

obj = Tile(x=1,y=2,tile_type="Type", method=my_method)
```